# how to form comma separated string from bson array using asp.net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, api, csv, asp.net-core, json.net

I have an api based on `asp.net core 2.2` in which i am building up an array of ips(strings type) like this

```
 [HttpGet ("{nsp}/geolocation")]
    [ResponseCache (Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public async Task<dynamic> getLocation (string nsp) {
        nsp = "/"+nsp;
        // string ipInfoBaseUrl = "http://ip-api.com/json/";
        string baseUrl = "http://ip-api.com/batch";
        // string userIpAddress = "197.157.194.90";
        // string ipUrl = ipInfoBaseUrl + userIpAddress;

         // var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        // var result = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl,new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finals), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        // // var final = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserLocation>(result);
        // Console.WriteLine(finals+" --result-----");
        // return Ok(result);

        var match = new BsonDocument ();
        var group = new BsonDocument ();
        var project = new BsonDocument ();
        var sort = new BsonDocument ();
        var addFields = new BsonDocument ();

        var pipeline = new [] { new BsonDocument () };

         /* @Aggregation : Stage-1 */
        match = new BsonDocument ("$match",
            new BsonDocument {
                {
                    "nsp" , nsp
                }
            });

        /* @Aggregation : Stage-2 */
        group = new BsonDocument("$group", 
            new BsonDocument
                { {
                    "_id", "null"
                },
                { "geoLocations", 
                    new BsonDocument("$addToSet", "$visitor.ip") 
                }
        });

        /* @Aggregation : Stage-3 */
        project = new BsonDocument ("$project", new BsonDocument { { "_id", 0 }});


        pipeline = new [] { match, group,project};
        var list = await DbService.tickets.AggregateAsync<BsonDocument> (pipeline, new AggregateOptions { UseCursor = true, BatchSize = batchCount });
        while (await list.MoveNextAsync ()) {
            var list_real = new List<BsonValue> ();
            foreach (var data in list.Current.ToArray ()) {
                list_real.Add (data);
            }
            return list_real.ToJson ();
        }
        return new BsonArray ().ToJson ();
    }
```

It is returning result like this

```
  [
    {
    "  geoLocations": [
        "122.8.208.9",
        "196.62.107.243",
        "182.188.38.219",
        "39.50.244.198",
        "39.51.40.251",
        "103.20.134.56",
        "103.228.156.83",
        "202.143.125.21",
        "196.62.151.47",
        "45.116.232.50",
        "39.57.128.75",
        "103.18.8.60",
        "202.143.125.20",
        "182.190.252.96",
        "119.153.56.2",
        "46.101.89.227",
        "196.194.172.211",
        "192.168.20.186",
        "64.233.173.146",
        "104.236.195.147",
        "39.50.156.242",
        "103.255.5.58"
       ]
      }
    ]
```

How can i get comma separated string from this result like

```
"111.92.158.82","202.142.168.162","122.8.157.172",.....
```

From very first i am getting all ips from all documents from my collection and forming an array of ips.But my ultimate goal is to form a comma separated string from that array because i have to pass that comma separated string of ips into an api to get ips locations.

I am using `asp.net core` and `c#`. How can  i achieve this?

Comment: Why do you return `dynamic`?

Comment: Additionally `"111.92.158.82", "202.142.168.162",...` is not a comma separated string, which is `"111.92.158.82,202.142.168.162"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a single comma-separated result string containing all IP addresses, replace the method signature with `IEnumerable<string>`, and replace the bottom of the method with. Just use whatever you need for your result and get rid of the rest.

```cs
var list = await DbService.tickets.AggregateAsync<BsonDocument> (pipeline, 
           new AggregateOptions 
           {
             UseCursor = true, 
             BatchSize = batchCount 
           });
var result = new List<string>();       
while (await list.MoveNextAsync())             
    result.AddRange(list.Current.Cast<string>());

return string.Join(',', result);
```

I'm not sure why you're doing everything with `BsonDocuments`, you can just iterate over the data directly and return strings.

Also, consider upgrading to .NET Core 3, which you can then use C# 8's [async enumerable](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/01/09/iasyncenumerable-in-c-8/). You'll also be able to use the new JSON functionality [built-in](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/09/11/how-to-parse-json-in-net-core/) .NET Core 3.

This will return:

```cs
"122.8.208.9,196.62.107.243,182.188.38.219,<all the rest>"
```